# What is the difference between getting no prefix key and getting a prefix key with empty string value in get_bucket_lifecycle API response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I'm running a python program that uses boto3 `get_bucket_lifecycle_configuration` API to get lifecycles set on a given bucket. I'm getting the following response -

```
    {"Rules":[
          {
             "Filter":{
                "Prefix":""
             },
             "Status":"Enabled",
             "ID":"deleteIncompleteMPU",
             "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload":{
                "DaysAfterInitiation":1
             }
          },
          {
             "Filter":{
                
             },
             "Status":"Enabled",
             "NoncurrentVersionExpiration":{
                "NoncurrentDays":12
             },
             "Expiration":{
                "Days":210
             },
             "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload":{
                "DaysAfterInitiation":1
             },
             "Transitions":[
                {
                   "Days":30,
                   "StorageClass":"DEEP_ARCHIVE"
                }
             ],
             "ID":"all-curr-GDA-30-non-curr-delete-12"
          }
       ],
       "ResponseMetadata":{
     }
   }
}
```

My question is that for ID **deleteIncompleteMPU**, the prefix value is an empty string  `"Prefix":""` but for ID **all-curr-GDA-30-non-curr-delete-12** there is no Prefix key under the Filter key `"Filter":{ }`.
Don't both things signify that the rule is set on the entire bucket? If no, then what is the difference?

Comment: hi, i have the same question here. were you able to get a concrete answer?

Comment: No, I wasn't. Looked thoroughly in all AWS documentations. Will update here if I do find something